# Android - Share feature displays all whatsapp contacts

Tags: android, share, contacts, whatsapp

I have to develop an app that has share functionality like mynta.But my code displays all applications including whatsapp contact list.How to remove default whatsapp contacts.

I have used below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"));
```

Comment: Please give some code snippets or ask question in details..??

Comment: I have used below code:  

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"));

Comment: You want to share your content or message all installed app or specfic contact of whatsApp?

Comment: I have to share with all shareable installed apps